# How do I statically serve the concatenation of several directories to a single path with twisted?

Tags: static, twisted

This will serve the contents of "tmp" at "static":

```
from twisted.web.static import File
resource = File("/tmp")
root = Resource()
root.putChild("static", resource)
```

how do I go about serving the contents of /tmp and /tmp2 at static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a tiny `Resource` to do the dispatching to the sub-`Resources` (`Files` for each directory).  Here is some pseudocode that illustrates the idea:

```
class MyResource(Resource):
    def __init__(self, dir_a, dir_b):
         self.a = File(dir_a)
         self.b = File(dir_b)

    def render_GET(self, request):
         if request.path handled by self.a:
             return self.a.render_GET(request)
         elif request.path handled by self.b:
             return self.b.render_GET(request)
         else:
             return 404 not found request

root.putChild("static", MyResource('/tmpa', '/tmpb'))
```

To implement `request.path handled by self.X`, look at `File.getChild`.  You may need to do some path munging (maybe not).